# Yii2 custom entity attributes

Tags: php, mysql, gridview, yii2, many-to-many

I have an object with regular fields (attributes) and custom fields that can be created by the user in the UI. And there is a many-to-many relationship between objects and fields. The values are stored in the junction table.

[image: DB schema]

I've managed to display the custom fields as if they are regular ones in a `GridView`, but unable to find a resource efficient way to make sorting and filtering possible.

Is there a common approach to make the `ObjectSearch` model treat custom fields as regular ones by modifying the `Object` model, so the result query will have a column for each of the field, named with `Field.slug` and the value will be the `FieldValue.value`?

--- Update: Added current code ---

My current Object model, where `getAvailableFields()` returns all fields that can be assigned to this model ('db_model'), and `getFields()` that returns currently assigned fields with values from the junction table:

```
public static function getAvailableFields()
{
    return Field::find()
        ->where(['db_model' => 'device_info'])
        ->orderBy(['type' => SORT_DESC, 'name' => SORT_ASC])
        ->all();
}

public function getFields()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Field::className(), ['id' => 'field_id'])
        ->viaTable('entity_fields', ['article_id' => 'id'])
        ->leftJoin('entity_fields', '{{field}}.id=field_id')
        ->select('{{field}}.*, value')
        ->where(['article_id' => $this->id]);
}


/**
 * With all fields, even unassigned
 */
public function getFieldValuesObject()
{
    $availableFields = array_fill_keys(ArrayHelper::map($this->availableFields, 'slug', 'slug'), null);
    $fieldValues = ArrayHelper::map($this->fields, 'slug', 'value');

    $result = array_replace($availableFields, $fieldValues);

    return (object) $result;
}
```

I'm displaying these fields in the GridView by adding them into the `columns`:

```
foreach (DeviceInfo::getAvailableFields() as $field) {
    array_push($customColumns, [
        'attribute'=> 'fieldValuesObject.'.$field['slug'],
        'label' => Yii::t('app', $field['name']),
    ]);
}
```

Now the problem is in the ObjectSearch model, where I've been trying to do something like this:

```
foreach ($availableFields as $field) {
    $query->joinWith(['fields '.$field['slug']]);
}
```

In other words, my custom fields relations are dynamic, so I can't hard code them into the `joinWith()`.

Comment: What is `object_id` in field value table, are these object of same entity. Eg Person. Can `object_id` contains objects of different entities eg at a time it may hold a person's id or another row may contain company_id

Comment: The `object_id` is only for the Object entity. I have a separate `user_id`, `article_id` in the Field Value table for assignment to other tables, that are not shown on the image.

Comment: you should add the relevant code so that it becomes easy for the other person to suggest tweaks and additions into various sections, do add the code related to grid view and your searchmode that you are using with it

Comment: Sorry, I made an update to the question.